# ajax request to php file to inser

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mariadb

Can you please help me understand why my code result in double insert? I have javascript function making ajax request to save.php file to insert data to database, but every time I submit it will do it twice, but return only one id, no idea where from the second insert is made.

javascript/ajax function

```
function opnActPag () {
    var actDiv = document.getElementById('act_div');
    var actLstCont = document.getElementById('act_lst_cont');
    var actTag = document.getElementById('act_tag');
    var actTxt = document.getElementById('act_txt');
    var actClrTxt = document.getElementById('act_clr_txt');
    var actSubmTxt = document.getElementById('act_subm_txt');
    var actTxtArea = document.getElementById('act_txt_area');
    var actHidVal = document.getElementById('act_hid_val').value;
    var actHidUsr = document.getElementById('act_hid_usr').value;
    actDiv.style.display = 'block';
    opnActPag['closeActPag'] = function () {
        actDiv.style.display = 'none';
        actTxtArea.value = '';
    }
    opnActPag['addAct'] = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'save.php',
            data: { act_txt: actTxtArea.value), id: actHidVal, usr: actHidUsr },
            success : function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

Data comes from

```
<div class="act-back-drop" id="act_div">
    <div class="act-cont">
        <div class="act-page">
            <div class="act-cls-btn" onclick="opnActPag.closeActPag()">&times;</div>
            <div class="act-list-cont" id="act_lst_cont">
                <!--<div class="act-list-buble"><div class="act-buble-tag" id="act_tag">DATE NAME</div><div class="act-buble-text" id="act_txt">TEXT HOLDER</div></div>-->
            </div>
            <div class="act-text-cont">
                <textarea rows="6" class="act-text-inp" id="act_txt_area"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" value="" id="act_hid_val">
                <input type="hidden" value="Some user" id="act_hid_usr">
                <div class="act-text-btn-cont">
                    <div class="act-text-btn-no" id="act_clr_txt_" onclick="document.getElementById('act_txt_area_').value = '';">&#215;</div>
                    <div class="act-text-btn-ok" id="act_subm_txt" onclick="opnActPag.addAct()">&#10004;</div>
                    <!--<div class="act-text-btn"></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

save.php

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['act_txt']) && !empty($_POST['act_txt']) ){
    $sql = "select count(*) as count from actions where user_name = '".$_POST['usr']."' and info = '".preg_replace( "/[\r\n]+/", " ",htmlentities(trim($_POST['act_txt']), ENT_QUOTES))."' and level_3_id =".$_POST['id'].";";
    $ret = poke_db($sql,0,1);
    if( $ret[0]['count'] == 0 ){
        $sql = "insert into actions (user_name,info,level_3_id) values('".$_POST['usr']."','".preg_replace( "/[\r\n]+/", " ",htmlentities(trim($_POST['act_txt']), ENT_QUOTES))."','".$_POST['id']."');";
        $ret = poke_db($sql,0,0);
    }
    echo $ret;
}
?>
```

php db connection function

```
$srv = "localhost";
$usr = "root";
$pas = "pass";
$db_name = "dbname";
function poke_db($sql,$multi,$array){
    global $db_name;
    global $srv;
    global $usr;
    global $pas;
    $servername = $srv;
    $username = $usr;
    $password = $pas;
    $dbname = $db_name;
    $conn = mysqli_init();
    $conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $conn->real_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('[ERR] '.$conn->connect_error);
    }
    if( !$conn -> query($sql) ){
        die('[ERR] ' . $conn -> error);
    }
    if( $multi == 1 ){
        $result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
    }else{
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    }
    if( $array == 1 ){
        if( mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0 ){
            $i=0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $out_array[$i] = $row;
                ++$i;
            }
        }else{
            $out_array = null;
        }
        return $out_array;
    }else{
        if( isset($id) ){
            return $id;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: My first guess would be that you didn't use `event.preventDefault()` on your form submit, causing your form to submit and your Ajax to submit (hence double entry)

Comment: FYI you don't need both `isset()` and `!empty()`. `empty()` checks if it's set automatically.

Comment: @icecub I was thinking the same thing, but there's no form or submit button in the HTML.

Comment: @easleyfixed Why does there have to be a form? They have a JS function that gets the values from the inputs.

Comment: @Barmar Ye you're right. Even if it's a form, the function isn't called with a submit button. My bad

Comment: I forgot the js tends to defy common HTML logic sometimes.

Comment: Check the Network tab of DevTools to see if you're making multiple calls to the server. Use an XHR breakpoint to see where the calls are coming from.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query` with SQL injections is a very large issue... also not sure why you are using that functions are your queries currently are single calls.

Comment: @Barmar I had a look into the network part of devtools and can only see one request per click. Yet two records show up in database.

Comment: Does the HTTP access log also show only one call to the URL?

Comment: Sorry, where would I find that log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why my code was doing double insert. In my php db connection I have this bit

```
if( !$conn -> query($sql) ){
    die('[ERR] ' . $conn -> error);
}
```

By testing if query worked unintentionally was already inserting record in. Removed it from the code and problem is gone. What made me to realize it was not ajax was another block of code in php that was inserting two records too, so it had to be only one thing.